How do i make the player in my shooter game rotate along with the mouse?
I wanted the player to follow the mouse direction as it moves so it can aim more than 4 directions.
I did this code to rotate it but it didn't work.
    def rotate(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        angle = degrees(atan2(mouse_pos.x, mouse_pos.y)) - 90
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.original_image, angle, 1)

I struggled for a long time on this, but i couldn't seem to find the issue.
main.py
     
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from pytmx.util_pygame import load_pygame
from support import *
from groups import *
 
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Survivor')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.load_folder()
 
        # Groups
        self.all_sprites = AllSprites()
        self.collision_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
        self.cursor = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("cursor.png"), (32,32))
 
 
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
 
        self.setup()
 
 
 
    def load_folder(self):
        self.characters = import_folder("characters")
 
    def setup(self):
        map =  load_pygame("data/world.tmx")
 
        for x, y, image in map.get_layer_by_name("Main").tiles():
            Sprite((x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE), image, self.all_sprites)
            pass
 
        for x, y, image in map.get_layer_by_name("Collision").tiles():
             Sprite((x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE), image, (self.all_sprites, self.collision_sprites))
 
        for obj in map.get_layer_by_name("Entities"):
            if obj.name == "Player":
                self.player = Player((obj.x, obj.y), self.characters[0], self.all_sprites, self.collision_sprites)
 
            if obj.name == "Enemy":
                self.enemy1 = Enemy((obj.x, obj.y), self.characters[randint(0,20)], self.player,self.all_sprites, 
self.collision_sprites)
 
            if obj.name == "Enemy2":
                self.enemy2 = Enemy((obj.x, obj.y), self.characters[randint(0,20)], self.player,self.all_sprites, self.collision_sprites)
    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            dt = self.clock.tick(60) / 1000
 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
 
            self.all_sprites.update(dt)
 
            self.display_surface.fill("black")
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.player.rect.center)
 
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 
            self.display_surface.blit(self.cursor, pos)
 
            pygame.display.update()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.run()

sprites.py
from settings import *
from math import atan2, degrees
 
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, surf, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = surf
        self.rect = self.image.get_frect(center= pos)
 
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surf, pos, direction, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
 
        self.image = surf
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
 
        self.direction = direction
        self.speed = 850
 
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, direction==-1, False)
 
    def update(self, dt):
        self.rect.x += self.direction * self.speed*dt
 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, surf,groups,collision_sprites):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.all_sprites = groups
        surf = pygame.transform.scale(surf, (80, 53*2))
        self.original_image = pygame.transform.rotate(surf, 90)
        self.original_image = self.original_image
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center= pos)
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(-30,0)
 
        self.bullet_surf = pygame.image.load("bullets/player bullet.png")
 
 
        self.speed = 500
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2()
        self.collision_sprites = collision_sprites
 
        self.can_shoot = True
        self.duration = 400
        self.start_time = 0
 
        self.flipx = False
        self.flipy = False
 
 
    def collision(self, direction):
        for sprite in self.collision_sprites:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
                if direction == "horizontal":
                    if self.direction.x > 0:
                        self.rect.right = sprite.rect.left
                    if self.direction.x < 0:
                        self.rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                else:
                    if self.direction.y > 0:
                        self.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
                    if self.direction.y < 0:
                        self.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
 
    def cooldown(self):
        if self.can_shoot == False:
            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if current_time - self.start_time >= self.duration:
                self.can_shoot = True
 
    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
 
        self.direction.x = int(keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]) - int(keys[pygame.K_LEFT])
        self.direction.y = int(keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) - int(keys[pygame.K_UP])
        self.direction = self.direction.normalize() if self.direction else self.direction
 
        if mouse[0] and self.can_shoot:
            self.can_shoot = False
            self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            Bullet(self.bullet_surf, self.rect.center, -1 if self.flipx else 1, self.all_sprites)
        self.cooldown()
 
 
    # def flip_image(self):
    #     if self.direction:
    #         self.flipx = self.direction.x < 0
    #     if self.direction.y > 0:
    #     if self.direction.y < 0:
    #
    #     self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(pygame.transform.flip(self.original_image, self.flipx, False))
 
    def rotate(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        angle = degrees(atan2(mouse_pos.x, mouse_pos.y)) - 90
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.original_image, angle, 1)
 
    def move(self, dt):
        self.rotate()
 
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed * dt
        self.collision("horizontal")
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y * self.speed * dt
        self.collision("vertical")
 
    def update(self, dt):
        self.input()
        self.move(dt)
 
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, surf, player, groups, collision_sprites):
        super().__init__(groups)
        surf = pygame.transform.scale(surf, (80, 53 * 2))
        self.original_image = pygame.transform.rotate(surf, 270)
        self.original_image = self.original_image
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(-30, 0)
        self.speed = randint(300, 400)
        self.player = player
        self.direction = pygame.Vector2()
        self.collision_sprites = collision_sprites
 
        self.flip = False
 
    def collision(self, direction):
        for sprite in self.collision_sprites:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(self.rect):
                if direction == "horizontal":
                    if self.direction.x > 0:
                        self.rect.right = sprite.rect.left
                    if self.direction.x < 0:
                        self.rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                else:
                    if self.direction.y > 0:
                        self.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
                    if self.direction.y < 0:
                        self.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
 
    def move(self, dt):
        player_pos = pygame.Vector2(self.player.rect.center)
        enemy_pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
 
        distance = player_pos.distance_to(enemy_pos)
 
        if distance > 100:
            self.direction = (player_pos - enemy_pos).normalize()
 
            self.rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed * dt
            self.collision("horizontal")
            self.rect.y += self.direction.y * self.speed * dt
            self.collision("vertical")
 
            self.flip = self.direction.x > 0
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.original_image, self.flip, False)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
 
    def update(self, dt):
        self.move(dt)

This is the code to main.py and sprites.py. I struggled to find any issues, but possible answers would be helpful

Please [edit] to include a [mre]. Do not link to external sites, the links may break. Make your question self-contained. It's hard if not impossible to answer your question with only three lines of code. What do you expect? What do you observe instead? I voted to close as "needs debugging details"

you need to subtract the player position from the mouse position to get the relative position of the mouse with respect to the player. As you have now the angle refers to the absolute position of the mouse (which takes the top left corner of the screen as the zero coordinate)
